# IsAuthenticated Permission Error Cannot Input Token from Login

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

how to authenticate using tokens in django DRF?

I'm trying to create a token authentication system using rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated in views, but I can't input tokens, token status has not been entered, I create views like this,

[image: django views]

I read it here (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), and I adjusted it like the documentation but it still doesn't work, I tried using postman to check the response but it's still the same,

[image: testing using postman]

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) you have to make a header. Your request would be something like this:

[image]

in fact in postman you have to put your token as `Headers` option not in `Authorization` option.

Comment: I've tried it but still get the same response

Comment: I think you have to share more information about the response, your settings, ... . Check that you just made project settings correctly [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

Comment: solved, thanks for your answer